# Turning th text by 90 degrees results in far off text

Tags: html, css, css-tables

i want to turn some headers of a table in my admin, but there is a css stylesheet that kind of comes with the system (I can easily add stuff though). To achieve this I created the `rotate` class but I cannot make it fit into a normal column (`th`).

This results in:
[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

But my current state has the second ("Hi") table header shifted into the first and the next ones accordingly. This way it consumes too much space and it looks really bad Also I want the headlines to vertically "stretch" the table head if needed.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=B612:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');


/* VARIABLE DEFINITIONS */
:root {
  --primary: #727272;
  --secondary: #8fb3e2;
  --accent: #000000;
  --primary-fg: #fff;

  --body-fg: #333;
  --body-bg: #fff;
  --body-quiet-color: #666;
  --body-loud-color: #000;

  --header-color: #ffc;
  --header-branding-color: var(--accent);
  --header-bg: var(--secondary);
  --header-link-color: var(--primary-fg);

  --breadcrumbs-fg: #000000;
  --breadcrumbs-link-fg: var(--body-bg);
  --breadcrumbs-bg: var(--primary);

  --link-fg: #292929;
  --link-hover-color: #036;
  --link-selected-fg: #5b80b2;

  --hairline-color: #e8e8e8;
  --border-color: #ccc;

  --error-fg: #ba2121;

  --message-success-bg: #dfd;
  --message-warning-bg: #ffc;
  --message-error-bg: #ffefef;

  --darkened-bg: #f8f8f8; /* A bit darker than --body-bg */
  --selected-bg: #e4e4e4; /* E.g. selected table cells */
  --selected-row: #ffc;

  --button-fg: #fff;
  --button-bg: var(--primary);
  --button-hover-bg: #609ab6;
  --default-button-bg: var(--secondary);
  --default-button-hover-bg: #205067;
  --close-button-bg: #888; /* Previously #bbb, contrast 1.92 */
  --close-button-hover-bg: #747474;
  --delete-button-bg: #ba2121;
  --delete-button-hover-bg: #a41515;

  --object-tools-fg: var(--button-fg);
  --object-tools-bg: var(--close-button-bg);
  --object-tools-hover-bg: var(--close-button-hover-bg);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --primary: #264b5d;
    --primary-fg: #eee;

    --body-fg: #eeeeee;
    --body-bg: #121212;
    --body-quiet-color: #e0e0e0;
    --body-loud-color: #ffffff;

    --breadcrumbs-link-fg: #e0e0e0;
    --breadcrumbs-bg: var(--primary);

    --link-fg: #81d4fa;
    --link-hover-color: #4ac1f7;
    --link-selected-fg: #6f94c6;

    --hairline-color: #272727;
    --border-color: #353535;

    --error-fg: #e35f5f;
    --message-success-bg: #006b1b;
    --message-warning-bg: #583305;
    --message-error-bg: #570808;

    --darkened-bg: #212121;
    --selected-bg: #1b1b1b;
    --selected-row: #00363a;

    --close-button-bg: #333333;
    --close-button-hover-bg: #666666;
  }
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    color: var(--body-fg);
    background: var(--body-bg);
}

/* LINKS */

a:link, a:visited {
    color: var(--link-fg);
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.15s, background 0.15s;
}

a:focus, a:hover {
    color: var(--link-hover-color);
}

a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

a.section:link, a.section:visited {
    color: var(--header-link-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.section:focus, a.section:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* GLOBAL DEFAULTS */

p, ol, ul, dl {
    margin: .2em 0 .8em 0;
}

p {
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 140%;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
}

h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 1em 0 .5em 0;
}

h2.subhead {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: .8em 0 .3em 0;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
    font-weight: bold;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 1em 0 .8em 0;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 1.5em 0 .5em 0;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

ul > li {
    list-style-type: square;
    padding: 1px 0;
}

li ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

li, dt, dd {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

dt {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

dd {
    margin-left: 0;
}

form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
}

blockquote {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #777;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 5px solid #ddd;
}

code, pre {
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", Monaco, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

pre.literal-block {
    margin: 10px;
    background: var(--darkened-bg);
    padding: 6px 8px;
}

code strong {
    color: #930;
}

hr {
    clear: both;
    color: var(--hairline-color);
    background-color: var(--hairline-color);
    height: 1px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
}

/* TEXT STYLES & MODIFIERS */

.small {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.mini {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.help, p.help, form p.help, div.help, form div.help, div.help li {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
}

div.help ul {
     margin-bottom: 0;
}

.help-tooltip {
    cursor: help;
}

p img, h1 img, h2 img, h3 img, h4 img, td img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.quiet, a.quiet:link, a.quiet:visited {
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
    font-weight: normal;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

/* TABLES */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: var(--border-color);
}

td, th {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 8px;
}

th {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
}

div.rotate {
    /* all: revert; */
    vertical-align: bottom;
    /* position: relative; */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width: 20px;
    max-width: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
    background: var(--darkened-bg);
}

thead th,
tfoot td {
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: var(--body-bg);
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
}

tfoot td {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
}

thead th.required {
    color: var(--body-loud-color);
}

tr.alt {
    background: var(--darkened-bg);
}

tr:nth-child(odd), .row-form-errors {
    background: var(--body-bg);
}

tr:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(even) .errorlist,
tr:nth-child(odd) + .row-form-errors,
tr:nth-child(odd) + .row-form-errors .errorlist {
    background: var(--darkened-bg);
}

/* SORTABLE TABLES */

thead th {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    line-height: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: var(--darkened-bg);
}

thead th a:link, thead th a:visited {
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
}

thead th.sorted {
    background: var(--selected-bg);
}

thead th.sorted .text {
    padding-right: 42px;
}

table thead th .text span {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    display: block;
}

table thead th .text a {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}

table thead th .text a:focus, table thead th .text a:hover {
    background: var(--selected-bg);
}

thead th.sorted a.sortremove {
    visibility: hidden;
}

table thead th.sorted:hover a.sortremove {
    visibility: visible;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions {
    display: block;
    padding: 9px 5px 0 5px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortpriority {
    font-size: .8em;
    min-width: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: 3px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a {
    position: relative;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../img/sorting-icons.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 14px auto;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove:after {
    content: '\\';
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 3px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove:focus:after,
table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove:hover:after {
    color: var(--link-fg);
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove:focus,
table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove:hover {
    background-position: 0 -14px;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.ascending {
    background-position: 0 -28px;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.ascending:focus,
table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.ascending:hover {
    background-position: 0 -42px;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.descending {
    top: 1px;
    background-position: 0 -56px;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.descending:focus,
table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.descending:hover {
    background-position: 0 -70px;
}
```

```html
<body class="change-list">
  <!-- Container -->
  <div id="container">
    <div class="main shifted" id="main">
      <button class="sticky toggle-nav-sidebar" id="toggle-nav-sidebar" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
      <div id="content-start" class="content" tabindex="-1">
        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content" class="">
          <h1>Select Situation to change</h1>
          <div id="content-main">
            <ul class="object-tools">
           </ul>
            <div class="module filtered" id="changelist">
              <div class="changelist-form-container">
                <form id="changelist-form" method="post" novalidate=""><input type="hidden">
                  <div class="results">
                    <table id="result_list">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="action-toggle">
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <div class="rotate">hi</div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              <div class="rotate">stat1</div>
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              <div class="rotate">huge buttontext</div>
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              ident
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              timestamp
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>

                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              name
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              Store
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              Adress
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="action-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="_selected_action" value="15" class="action-select"></td>
                          <th class="field-get_status"><a href="..."><span class="dot" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span></a></th>
                          <td class="field-get_powerstate"><a href="..."><span class="dot" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span></a></td>
                          <td class="field-get_persistence"><a href="..."><span class="dot" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span></a></td>
                          <td class="field-get_serial"><a href="..."><span style="font-weight: bold;">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span></a></td>
                          <td class="field-get_onoff_timestamp">18. Feb 2020 - 10:10:48</td>
                          <td class="field-get_shelf_name"></td>
                          <td class="field-get_store">store</td>
                          <td class="field-get_store_address">None, None - None</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END Container -->
</body>
```

Comment: Have you considered CSS writing-mode?

Comment: I tried it, but did not really get a good result. Would you think it should be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Causing the problem here in your `div.rotate` class. You set `height: 80px;` and `max-height: 80px;`, So when you rotate the text, it'll make an space or margin.

I suggest to change your *tranformation* from `transform: rotate(-90deg);` to `transform: translateX(155%) translateY(40%) rotate(-90deg);`. By doing so, you can set the **x** and **y** axis of the text.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=B612:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');


/* VARIABLE DEFINITIONS */
:root {
  --primary: #727272;
  --secondary: #8fb3e2;
  --accent: #000000;
  --primary-fg: #fff;

  --body-fg: #333;
  --body-bg: #fff;
  --body-quiet-color: #666;
  --body-loud-color: #000;

  --header-color: #ffc;
  --header-branding-color: var(--accent);
  --header-bg: var(--secondary);
  --header-link-color: var(--primary-fg);

  --breadcrumbs-fg: #000000;
  --breadcrumbs-link-fg: var(--body-bg);
  --breadcrumbs-bg: var(--primary);

  --link-fg: #292929;
  --link-hover-color: #036;
  --link-selected-fg: #5b80b2;

  --hairline-color: #e8e8e8;
  --border-color: #ccc;

  --error-fg: #ba2121;

  --message-success-bg: #dfd;
  --message-warning-bg: #ffc;
  --message-error-bg: #ffefef;

  --darkened-bg: #f8f8f8; /* A bit darker than --body-bg */
  --selected-bg: #e4e4e4; /* E.g. selected table cells */
  --selected-row: #ffc;

  --button-fg: #fff;
  --button-bg: var(--primary);
  --button-hover-bg: #609ab6;
  --default-button-bg: var(--secondary);
  --default-button-hover-bg: #205067;
  --close-button-bg: #888; /* Previously #bbb, contrast 1.92 */
  --close-button-hover-bg: #747474;
  --delete-button-bg: #ba2121;
  --delete-button-hover-bg: #a41515;

  --object-tools-fg: var(--button-fg);
  --object-tools-bg: var(--close-button-bg);
  --object-tools-hover-bg: var(--close-button-hover-bg);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --primary: #264b5d;
    --primary-fg: #eee;

    --body-fg: #eeeeee;
    --body-bg: #121212;
    --body-quiet-color: #e0e0e0;
    --body-loud-color: #ffffff;

    --breadcrumbs-link-fg: #e0e0e0;
    --breadcrumbs-bg: var(--primary);

    --link-fg: #81d4fa;
    --link-hover-color: #4ac1f7;
    --link-selected-fg: #6f94c6;

    --hairline-color: #272727;
    --border-color: #353535;

    --error-fg: #e35f5f;
    --message-success-bg: #006b1b;
    --message-warning-bg: #583305;
    --message-error-bg: #570808;

    --darkened-bg: #212121;
    --selected-bg: #1b1b1b;
    --selected-row: #00363a;

    --close-button-bg: #333333;
    --close-button-hover-bg: #666666;
  }
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    color: var(--body-fg);
    background: var(--body-bg);
}

/* LINKS */

a:link, a:visited {
    color: var(--link-fg);
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.15s, background 0.15s;
}

a:focus, a:hover {
    color: var(--link-hover-color);
}

a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

a.section:link, a.section:visited {
    color: var(--header-link-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.section:focus, a.section:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* GLOBAL DEFAULTS */

p, ol, ul, dl {
    margin: .2em 0 .8em 0;
}

p {
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 140%;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
}

h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 1em 0 .5em 0;
}

h2.subhead {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: .8em 0 .3em 0;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
    font-weight: bold;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 1em 0 .8em 0;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 1.5em 0 .5em 0;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

ul > li {
    list-style-type: square;
    padding: 1px 0;
}

li ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

li, dt, dd {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

dt {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

dd {
    margin-left: 0;
}

form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
}

blockquote {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #777;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 5px solid #ddd;
}

code, pre {
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", Monaco, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

pre.literal-block {
    margin: 10px;
    background: var(--darkened-bg);
    padding: 6px 8px;
}

code strong {
    color: #930;
}

hr {
    clear: both;
    color: var(--hairline-color);
    background-color: var(--hairline-color);
    height: 1px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
}

/* TEXT STYLES & MODIFIERS */

.small {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.mini {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.help, p.help, form p.help, div.help, form div.help, div.help li {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
}

div.help ul {
     margin-bottom: 0;
}

.help-tooltip {
    cursor: help;
}

p img, h1 img, h2 img, h3 img, h4 img, td img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.quiet, a.quiet:link, a.quiet:visited {
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
    font-weight: normal;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

/* TABLES */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: var(--border-color);
}

td, th {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 8px;
}

th {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
}

div.rotate {
    /* all: revert; */
    vertical-align: bottom;
    /* position: relative; */
    /* transform: rotate(-90deg); */
    transform: translateX(155%) translateY(40%) rotate(-90deg);
    width: 20px;
    max-width: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
    background: var(--darkened-bg);
}

thead th,
tfoot td {
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: var(--body-bg);
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
}

tfoot td {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--hairline-color);
}

thead th.required {
    color: var(--body-loud-color);
}

tr.alt {
    background: var(--darkened-bg);
}

tr:nth-child(odd), .row-form-errors {
    background: var(--body-bg);
}

tr:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(even) .errorlist,
tr:nth-child(odd) + .row-form-errors,
tr:nth-child(odd) + .row-form-errors .errorlist {
    background: var(--darkened-bg);
}

/* SORTABLE TABLES */

thead th {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    line-height: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: var(--darkened-bg);
}

thead th a:link, thead th a:visited {
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
}

thead th.sorted {
    background: var(--selected-bg);
}

thead th.sorted .text {
    padding-right: 42px;
}

table thead th .text span {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    display: block;
}

table thead th .text a {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}

table thead th .text a:focus, table thead th .text a:hover {
    background: var(--selected-bg);
}

thead th.sorted a.sortremove {
    visibility: hidden;
}

table thead th.sorted:hover a.sortremove {
    visibility: visible;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions {
    display: block;
    padding: 9px 5px 0 5px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortpriority {
    font-size: .8em;
    min-width: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: 3px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a {
    position: relative;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../img/sorting-icons.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 14px auto;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove:after {
    content: '\\';
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 3px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--body-quiet-color);
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove:focus:after,
table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove:hover:after {
    color: var(--link-fg);
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove:focus,
table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.sortremove:hover {
    background-position: 0 -14px;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.ascending {
    background-position: 0 -28px;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.ascending:focus,
table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.ascending:hover {
    background-position: 0 -42px;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.descending {
    top: 1px;
    background-position: 0 -56px;
}

table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.descending:focus,
table thead th.sorted .sortoptions a.descending:hover {
    background-position: 0 -70px;
}
```

```html
<body class="change-list">
  <!-- Container -->
  <div id="container">
    <div class="main shifted" id="main">
      <button class="sticky toggle-nav-sidebar" id="toggle-nav-sidebar" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
      <div id="content-start" class="content" tabindex="-1">
        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content" class="">
          <h1>Select Situation to change</h1>
          <div id="content-main">
            <ul class="object-tools">
           </ul>
            <div class="module filtered" id="changelist">
              <div class="changelist-form-container">
                <form id="changelist-form" method="post" novalidate=""><input type="hidden">
                  <div class="results">
                    <table id="result_list">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="action-toggle">
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <div class="rotate">hi</div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              <div class="rotate">stat1</div>
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              <div class="rotate">huge buttontext</div>
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              ident
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              timestamp
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>

                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              name
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              Store
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <span>
                              Adress
                            </span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="action-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="_selected_action" value="15" class="action-select"></td>
                          <th class="field-get_status"><a href="..."><span class="dot" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span></a></th>
                          <td class="field-get_powerstate"><a href="..."><span class="dot" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span></a></td>
                          <td class="field-get_persistence"><a href="..."><span class="dot" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: red; display: inline-block;"></span></a></td>
                          <td class="field-get_serial"><a href="..."><span style="font-weight: bold;">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span></a></td>
                          <td class="field-get_onoff_timestamp">18. Feb 2020 - 10:10:48</td>
                          <td class="field-get_shelf_name"></td>
                          <td class="field-get_store">store</td>
                          <td class="field-get_store_address">None, None - None</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END Container -->
</body>
```

Comment: This works great. One question though: Why did you use % in the translation and not px/em?

Comment: Sorry if I confuse you. You can use px/em if you want. Although using % may give you trouble when resizing the screen as it also adjust its *x* and *y* value, you use this ```.rotate``` class on div. For me, I used % on div's and px/em for fonts, so you can just change it if you want. *p.s.* change the value as well :)